# Clarify the rules for "E-l Erech" and "Lamenatze'ach' (Psalm 20) on non-Tachanun days

Tags: tefilla, tachanun

I am confused regarding the rules of when to omit *E-l Erech Apayim* (the paragraph before taking out the Torah) and when to omit Psalm 20 (said after the Torah is returned (Nusach Ashkenaz).

My understanding:

*E-l Erech* is said on Mon. & Thurs. only. But, I'm not sure if it is omitted on *all* days when Tachanun is omitted, such as today, Lag B'Omer, or not. My shul said it this morning. But, when Rosh Hodesh or Chanukah is on Mon. or Thurs. they don't. Are there different minhagim, here, or did my shul err, this morning?

Lamentze'ach (Psalm 20) - I know there is a list of omitted days in the siddur. But, it doesn't seem dependent on when Tachanun is omitted. We said it today. I don't think days like Tu B'Shevat or Pesach Sheni (Some omit Tachanun on Pesach Sheni) are omitted. But it's omitted on Rosh Hodesh, Purim and Chanukah and Tisha B'Av. What rules govern its omission?

Comment: It’s normally assumed that Kel Erech Apaim and Lamnatzeach follow the same rules, and are omitted on a subset of the days on which tachanun is omitted (nusach ashkenaz and sefard)

Comment: AFAIK Chabad never say kel erech apaim nor lamnatzeach on a non-tachanun day

Comment: Heidenheim says that we omit אל ארך אפים on ראש חודש, חול המועד, חנכה and both פורים. At למנצח he adds to this תשעה באב, ערב יום כיפור and ערב פסח, while says that many others omit it on ערב שבעות, ראש השנה, סכות and אסרו חג as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ואפילו בימים שאין אומרים תחנון אומרים למנצח מלבד בראש חודש וחנוכה ופורים וע"פ וערב יום כפור וט"ו באב [מנהגים וע"ל סי' תקנ"ט]:
>
> Even on days where *tachanun* is not said we say *Lamnatzeiach* except Rosh Chodesh, Chanukah, Purim, Erev Pesach, Erev Yom Kippur, and Tu B'Av.

Rema to [OC 131:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.131.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

The Mishnah Berura adds ([131:35](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.131.35?lang=bi)):

> והנה כל אלו הסעיפים הוא לענין תחנון אבל למנצח אומרים בכולם מלבד בר"ח וחנוכה ופורים וערב פסח וערב יוה"כ וט"ב וה"ה שאין אומרים בשנה מעוברת ביום י"ד וט"ו באדר ראשון גם אין אומרים אותו בבית האבל [אחרונים] עוד כתבו דאל ארך אפים ולמנצח דינם שוה:
>
> And all this that we have been discussing [days when *tachanun* is omitted] is [only] about *tachanun*, but *Lamnatzeiach* is said on all of them except Rosh Chodesh, Chanukah, Purim, Erev Pesach, Erev Yom Kippur, Tu B'Av, and also it is not said during a leap year on 14 and 15 of Adar I, and also not in a mourner's house. And it has been written that *Kel Erech Apaim* and *Lamnatzeach* have the same rule.

This is Ashkenazic halacha. Sefaradim don't say *Lamnatzeiach* whenever *tachanun* is skipped, even if it's skipped for something like a *brit* or wedding. This has been my experience, and also implicitly sourced above by it being the Rema who limits skipping *Lamnatzeiach*.

Comment: Note that Rav Yaakov Emden says it is customary to omit them on every erev chag and isru chag.

Comment: I suppose it's just a partial answer for the psalm, as it assumes that these two are said on the same days (which is not the case as R' Emden and R' Heidenheim shows).

Comment: +1 - I'll try to check source later. Offhand, is there any theory / rule behind *lamenatze'ach* as to why it doesn't necessarily coincide with Tachanun omission?

Comment: your MB reference is 131:35 not 25 but I cant edit just one character

Comment: @Jon good catch, fixed